# Why CCRC tool is necessary when people can configure remote replica in their clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

We are having multiple replica and we are configuring our clearcase license server.

Some times people even would configure to remote replica.

But recently our team member in north america wanted to access our clearcase contents (we are having replicas in india), So some people suggested CCRC.

When geographic distance grows , will it affect performance ? is that the reason people goes to CCRC?

Why CCRC tool is necessary?

we are using Clearcase UCM. Whether deliver and rebase operation is supported in CCRC? is it possible to have both dynamic and snapshot view with CCRC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCRC tool was primarily adopted because of a license cost issue ;)

The main difference is that there is no regular synchronization between replica, since CCRC is a light client using a CCRC server to update web view (no replica here).
The network load actually decreased with CCRC (as opposed to the multitool syncs).

However that means you would be using only **web views**, which are snapshot views "over the WAN": no more dynamic views.
Their view workspace are stored on the CCRC server. See also "[About ClearCase views (in CCRC)](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm)".
And you don't have a `cleartool` CLI (you have a slightly less complete CCRC CLI though: [rcleartool](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728), with CCRC 8.0).

UCM is (almost) supported: deliver and rebase.
For instance, [CCRC7.1 provides an Enhanced Rebase and Deliver preview](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.relnotes.doc/topics/c_cc_relnotes_features_71.htm#ccfeatures__ccrc_rebase_deliver).

As [mentioned yesterday](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14913512&tstart=0#14913512):

> I think you'll find that the eventual plan for ClearTeam Explorer is that it will (eventually) supercede ALL ClearCase GUI's.
>   So, while it doesn't do everything that all the other GUIs do, it certainly does more in 8.0 than CCRC did in 7.1.x.
>   So, while you can't do completely without the rich client now for some admin usecases, it certainly does most of what an end-user would need.
>
> What I would say is to have the users try it out and see if it suits their needs.
>
> ClearTeam Explorer is not YET a complete replacement for all the ClearCase GUIs. It is a work in progress. The same can be said for the `rcleartool` command.